# Angular Material: Selection list - how to focus on the first element

Tags: angular-material

I create a component more or less dynamically. Within it I have a `selection-list` and I want to focus (NOT select) the very first element.

```
 <mat-selection-list #myList>
   @for (prodCat of list); track prodCat.id; let first = $first) {
       <mat-list-option togglePosition="before">
        {{ prodCat.name }}
       </mat-list-option>
    }
  </mat-selection-list>
```

And I have in my `*.ts` code something like

```
    @ViewChild('myList', { static: true }) matSelList: ElementRef;        
    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      console.log('focus??', this.matSelList);
      this.matSelList?.nativeElement.focus();
    }
```

First of all the `matSelList` is always empty although its seen in the DOM. Second I'm not sure if this is an appropriate approach since I want to focus (NOT select) the first element. Is there a better way to get a grip of the first `mat-list-option`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ElementRef` we can take the view child of `MatSelectionList`, which gives us access to the `options` where we choose the first option using `first` property and then finally call `focus`!

ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatListModule, MatSelectionList } from '@angular/material/list';

/**
 * @title Basic list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatListModule],
})
export class ListOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('myList', { static: true }) matSelList: MatSelectionList;
  list = [
    { id: 1, name: 'one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three' },
  ];

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log('focus??', this.matSelList);
    this.matSelList?.options.first.focus();
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-selection-list #myList>
  @for (prodCat of list; track prodCat.id; let first = $first) {
  <mat-list-option togglePosition="before">
    {{ prodCat.name }}
  </mat-list-option>
  }
</mat-selection-list>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gh1qpj?file=src%2Fexample%2Flist-overview-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Flist-overview-example.html)

Comment: I wasn't sure where my basic error was located. I thought if you sample works than I have to change something. I figured out that the `{static:true}` was the root cause. But pointing me directly to the focus option helped a lot. Thx for your effort ;-)

Comment: Just a "bonus" question: You have an idea why the `mat-list-option` is rendered differently to a "regular" checkbox? I don't mean the font I mean more the space between the checkbox AND the text.

Comment: @LeO Angular material just has different styles set when its rendered inside the mat-list-option, we can override the CSS manually to get the desired result!

Comment: Perhaps you have an idea as well for https://stackoverflow.com/q/77986519/325868 ?