# Angular Material Lists: Nested option list

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to have an nested List with option for selection. I thought I can use Angular Materials option list. But somehow the result looks strange AND the keyboard navigation won't work.

```
<mat-selection-list #myList>
  @for (prodCat of list; track prodCat.id) {
  <mat-list-option togglePosition="before" [lines]="prodCat.childs.length+1">
    {{ prodCat.name }}
    <mat-selection-list >
    @for (subList of prodCat.childs; track subList.id){
      <mat-list-option togglePosition="before">
        {{subList.name}}      
      </mat-list-option>
    }
    </mat-selection-list>
  </mat-list-option>
  }
</mat-selection-list>
```

With a data structure like

```
  list = [
    { id: 1, name: 'one' , childs:[{id: 11, name: 'one-one'}, {id: 12, name: 'one-two'} ]},
    { id: 2, name: 'two' , childs:[{id: 21, name: 'two-one'}, {id: 22, name: 'two-two'}, {id:23, name: 'three-two'} ]},
    { id: 3, name: 'three' , childs:[{id: 31, name: 'three-one'}, {id: 32, name: 'three-two'}]},
  ];
```

I've created a sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gh1qpj-huexpu?file=src%2Fexample%2Flist-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are performing keyboard navigation, looks like `mat-list` is a better option, but we need to maintain the selections and insert the checkboxes manually, but it seems to work great!

ts

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCheckbox } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Basic list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['list-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ListOverviewExample {
  @ViewChildren(MatCheckbox)
  MatCheckboxes: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;

  items = [
    {
      name: 'first',
      subItems: [{ name: 'sth1' }, { name: 'sth2' }, { name: 'sth3' }],
    },
    {
      name: 'second',
      subItems: [
        { name: 'sadas1' },
        { name: 'stdfgdfsgh2' },
        { name: 'stgfhfgh3' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'thrid',
      subItems: [{ name: 'dfhfdg' }, { name: 'gfhfg' }, { name: 'fhfj3' }],
    },
  ];

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.MatCheckboxes.first.focus();
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-list>
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: $index; let outerIndex = $index"
  >
    <mat-list-item
      ><div>
        <mat-checkbox
          class="example-margin"
          id="outer-checkbox-{{outerIndex}}"
          name="outer-checkbox-{{outerIndex}}"
          [checked]="item.checked"
          (change)="item.checked =!item.checked"
        >
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </div></mat-list-item
    >
    <mat-list style="margin-left: 30px">
      <div
        *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems; trackBy: $index; let innerIndex = $index"
      >
        <mat-list-item
          ><div>
            <mat-checkbox
              id="outer-checkbox-{{innerIndex}}"
              name="outer-checkbox-{{innerIndex}}"
              class="example-margin"
              [checked]="subItem.checked"
              (change)="subItem.checked =!subItem.checked"
            >
              {{subItem.name}}
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div></mat-list-item
        >
      </div>
    </mat-list>
  </ng-container>
</mat-list>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnkg3h-xbt552?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.ts,app%2Flist-overview-example.html)